# How can I emulate/fake/immitate an SD card with a live connection to a computer?

Tags: hardware, sd-card, connectivity, usb-flash-drive

I have a machine in a remote location that contains an SD card slot as its only output. I would like to read the output without needing to physically go to the machine and remove the card.

My idea is to place a PC next to the machine and connect the SD card slot of the machine to a USB or serial port or some other input on the PC.

Is there a piece of hardware available will act to the machine like an SD card, but is in fact a cable which can be connected to a computer?

Comment: Not so much a programming question.  You might have better luck on superuser.com.

Comment: The "machine" is a PC, isn't it? (just checking)

Comment: ok, thanks for clarifying & apolgies just assuming that. Can you please tell us what you "machine" is? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a manufacturer of CF cards which store data back to a bluetooth attached storage device.
they are intended for use in digital SLR's to store to a bluetooth hard disk.

eye-fi make sd to wifi interface cards; which might replicate your data if it looks kind-of-like video or photos.
( they can provide a cf to sd adaptor that is compatible)

you could probably a solution like this for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks that eye-fi device looks extremely cool. I doubt my data looks enough like pictures but it's definitely worth investigating so I'll accept. Maybe they'll do some custom firmware for us anyway.

Comment: Similar to eye-fi is the flashair, but it's easier to repurpose to push and/or pull files.

Answer (score 0):

"I have a machine in a remote location that contains an SD card slot as its only output. I would like to read the output without needing to physically go to the machine and remove the card".

Could you conider a network connection (mount the SD card as a network drive), or something like http://www.uvnc.com/ which will let you see the remote desktop as a window on your own and examine the file in Windowss Explorer, Midnight Commander or similar?

If output is constantlly refreshed, just leave "tail" (Linux command, or http://www.baremetalsoft.com/wintail/ for windows) running in a commad shell.

Comment: I think your solution is based on the machine being a computer but it's not, it's a 3rd party hardware "black box" from our perspective. Thanks anyway.